# Convert stdin to one file per line

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to write a small script using the standard linux shell scripting tools (sed, awk, etc.) to create one output file per line of input. For example, given the following input file 'input':

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I would like to run the command.

```
$ cat input | my_prog
```

Where 'my_prog' is a script that creates three output files, out.1, out.2, out.3

```
$ cat out.1
line1 

$ cat out.2
line2

$ cat out.3
line3
```

Comment: This is part of a pipeline of commands that use sed and awk.  I was wondering if it was possible to have sed map each input line to a separate output pipe.  I think I will use ennuikiller's solution, replacing "echo $line > out.$count"  with my full pipeline of sed commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
count=0
for line in $(cat input)
do
echo $line > out.$count
let count=count+1
done
```

Comment: That splits each line per word. You should do `while read -r line ... done < input`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'open my $fh, ">out.$." && print $fh $_' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

using awk

```
awk '{print $0 > "out_"++d".txt"}' file
```

Comment: then you are doing it wrong. show your error messages, and what didn't work. provide more information on the failure next time!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" > out.$((++i))
done < /path/to/input
```